# How do I convert a numpy array of floats into an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a opencv image variable called `result`.
The shape of the array is (28800, 3) & has the following values

```
[[-9.10972506e-02 -9.10972506e-02 -9.10972506e-02]
 [-1.03304401e-01 -1.03304401e-01 -1.03304401e-01]
 [-1.05187558e-01 -1.05187558e-01 -1.05187558e-01]
...
 [-1.05294801e-01 -1.05294801e-01 -1.05294801e-01]
 [-1.06410049e-01 -1.06410049e-01 -1.06410049e-01]
 [-1.04490273e-01 -1.04490273e-01 -1.04490273e-01]
 [-7.67669156e-02 -7.67669156e-02 -7.67669156e-02]]
... You get the idea
```

I converted this to an RGB image format by using this.

```
result = result.reshape(( 144 ,  200, 3 ) )
```

These values are too small & get converted to int 0.
How can I convert this to an image that is actually visible & understandable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the float values by 255 and cast them to `uint8`

```
new = np.multiply(result.reshape((144,  200, 3)), 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: You can just do `new = (255 * ...).astype(np.uint8)`.  Multiplying by a scalar doesn't require using `np.multiply`, even though it's correct.  Also note that there are negative values here so multiplying by 255 then casting to uint8 may not provide the intended results.

Comment: That's a good observation. Then I'm not sure what kind of picture OP is expecting. Or where the data is coming from.